# Ruby Sinatra app not storing session variable correctly

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am following a guide on learning Ruby and Sinatra which had me write the following code for a card game (based off of [Play Your Cards Right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9V6mCxl7Up4)).

Here is the code

```
enable :sessions

get '/' do
    session[:deck] = []
    suits = %w[ Hearts Diamonds Clubs Spades ]
    values = %w[ Ace 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King ]
    suits.each do |suit|
        values.each do |value|
            session[:deck] << "#{value} of #{suit}"
        end
    end
    session[:deck].shuffle!
    session[:guesses] = -1
    redirect to('/play')
end

get '/:guess' do

    card = session[:deck].pop
    value = case card[0]
        when "J" then 11
        when "Q" then 12
        when "K" then 13
        else card.to_i
    end

    if (params[:guess] == 'higher' and value < session[:value]) or (params[:guess] == 'lower' and value > session[:value])
        "Game Over! The card was the #{card} (value #{value}), and you had #{session[:value]}. You managed to make #{session[:guesses]} correct guess#{'es' unless session[:guesses] == 1}. <a href='/'>Play Again</a>"
    else
        session[:guesses] += 1
        session[:value] = value
        "The card is the #{card} (value of #{value}). Do you think the next card will be <a href='/higher'>Higher</a> or <a href='/lower'>Lower</a>?"
    end
end
```

The game seems to play ok some of the time, however, for some reason, the session variable `value` seems to be overwritten with a new value before the IF statement executes.

I have no clue what could be wrong with the above code and why the `value` session variable is changing to a new value randomly when it shouldn't.

Please take a look at my code (or try to run it yourself) and tell me what could be wrong.

My `config.ru` file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
disable :run, :reload

require './play_your_cards_right.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Do you have the link to a working example?
Also are you using `shotgun` or `sinatra-reloader` ?

Comment: I'll set up a link to a working example soon. And I'm not sure whether I'm suing `shotgun` or `sinatra-reloader`. How can I check? I have a file called `restart.txt` that I `touch` in order to reload my application. I set up my Ruby server with Apache2 using Phusion Passenger.

Comment: Can you replace the `enable sessions` line with `use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: "notasecret"` for testing and see if that helps?

Comment: I just did that and the game behaves the same. I'm not sure where I can upload my code without paying - does the game work fine when you try it (if you've tried it)?

Comment: Use `Github` to share the source. Is this the entire source? Where is the route for `/play`?

Comment: That is the entire source. I've edited the question to include the `config.ru` file. The `/:guess` route will catch the request for `/play`. The first time this route executes it will initialize `session[:guesses]` to `0` and draw the first card.

Comment: So I got onto setting this up locally and it seems to work for me.
Here's what I get when I play and finally lose - `Game Over! The card was the 4 of Hearts (value 4), and you had 13. You managed to make 11 correct guesses. Play Again` Is there a particular sequence in which you see the error?